# What is the best way to check two List<T> lists for equality in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, equality

There are many ways to do this but I feel like I've missed a function or something.

Obviously `List == List` will use `Object.Equals()` and return `false`.

If every element of the list is equal and present in the same location in the opposite list then I would consider them to be equal.  I'm using value types, but a correctly implemented Data object should work in the same fashion (i.e I'm not looking for a shallow copied list, only that the *value* of each object within is the same).

I've tried searching and there are similar questions, but my question is an equality of every element, in an exact order.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308476/how-to-find-out-whether-two-icollectiont-collections-contain-the-same-objects

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)

Comment: using System.Linq;

Will that throw if the sequences are of differing length or they are out of order etc?

Comment: This method asks a question, so it shouldn't provide the answer by throwing. The only reason it should throw is if either of the sequences is a null reference.

Comment: sorry asked too quickly.  Will it return false if the sequences are of different length or out of order?

Comment: @Spence - Yes, SequenceEqual returns false when the sequences are different lengths or out-of-order: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

Comment: @Luke, out of order was not asked.

Comment: @leppie - I wasn't disputing your answer (+1 from me already). I was just confirming what Spence asked in his comment above.

Comment: yeah the new show more comments bit is annoying, you can miss the context of the comments.  cheers for your help guys.  Shame that my objects don't implement IEquatable :(

Answer (score 5):

Evil implementation is

```
if (List1.Count == List2.Count)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < List1.Count; i++)
   {
      if(List1[i] != List2[i])
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: This is almost exactly how the built-in SequenceEqual method works, as in leppie's answer. (Your version will return slightly faster than SequenceEqual if the collections have different lengths but it's restricted to IList<T>, whereas SequenceEqual will work with any IEnumerable<T>.)

Comment: Your implemented method needs to sort list items to be accurate

Comment: @HasanFathi OP says "If every element of the list is equal and present in the same location in the opposite list then I would consider them to be equal" -- that's what I'd also take to be the usual equality. You want an "equals in any order" logic.

Answer (score 3):

I put together this variation:

```
private bool AreEqual<T>(List<T> x, List<T> y)
{
    // same list or both are null
    if (x == y)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // one is null (but not the other)
    if (x== null || y == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // count differs; they are not equal
    if (x.Count != y.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!x[i].Equals(y[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The nerd in me also crawled out so I did a performance test against SequenceEquals, and this one has a slight edge.

Now, the question to ask; is this tiny, almost measurable performance gain worth adding the code to the code base and maintaining it? I very much doubt it ;o)

Answer (score 2):

I knocked up a quick extension method:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static bool Matches<T>(this List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
        {
            if (list1.Count != list2.Count) return false;
            for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list1[i] != list2[i]) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One can write a general purpose `IEqualityComparer<T>` for sequences. A simple one:

```
public class SequenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        return unchecked(obj.Aggregate(397, (x, y) => x * 31 + y.GetHashCode()));
    }
}
```

---

**A more fleshed out version**: which should be better performing.

```
public class SequenceEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>, 
                                           IEquatable<SequenceEqualityComparer<T>>
{
    readonly IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;

    public SequenceEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public override bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        // safer to use ReferenceEquals as == could be overridden
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        var xICollection = x as ICollection<T>;
        if (xICollection != null)
        {
            var yICollection = y as ICollection<T>;
            if (yICollection != null)
            {
                if (xICollection.Count != yICollection.Count)
                    return false;

                var xIList = x as IList<T>;
                if (xIList != null)
                {
                    var yIList = y as IList<T>;
                    if (yIList != null)
                    {
                        // optimization - loops from bottom
                        for (int i = xIList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                            if (!comparer.Equals(xIList[i], yIList[i]))
                                return false;

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return x.SequenceEqual(y, comparer);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 397;
            foreach (var item in sequence)
                hash = hash * 31 + comparer.GetHashCode(item);

            return hash;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(SequenceEqualityComparer<T> other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return this.comparer.Equals(other.comparer);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as SequenceEqualityComparer<T>);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return comparer.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This has a few features:

1. The comparison is done from bottom to top. There is more probability for collections differing at the end in typical use-cases.
2. An `IEqualityComparer<T>` can be passed to base the comparison for items in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use **linq** `SequenceEqual` to check for sequence equality because Equals method checks for reference equality.

```
bool isEqual = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

The `SequenceEqual()` method takes a second I`Enumerable<T>` sequence as a parameter, and performs a comparison, **element-by-element**, with the target (first) sequence. If the two sequences contain the **same number** of elements, and each element in the first sequence is equal to the corresponding element in the second sequence (using the *default equality comparer*) then `SequenceEqual()` `returns true`. Otherwise, `false` is returned.

Or if you don't care about elements order use `Enumerable.All` method:

```
var isEqual = list1.All(list2.Contains);
```

The second version also requires another check for Count because it would return true even if `list2` contains more elements than `list1`.