# How to find out whether two string arrays are equal to other

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two List<string> for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546925/comparing-two-liststring-for-equality)

How can I find out whether two arrays of string are equal to each other?

I used this, but it does not work, even though the contents of both are the same.

```
string[] array1 = new string[]{"A" , "B"}

string[] array2 = new string[]{"A" , "B"}

if(array1 == array2)  // it return false !!!!
{
  // 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static bool ArraysEqual<T>(T[] a1, T[] a2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(a1,a2))
        return true;

    if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
        return false;

    if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
        return false;

    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(a1[i], a2[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you have access to Linq, use `SequenceEqual`. Otherwise, simply provide the code to first check if the arrays are equal length, and then if items are equal at each index.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the following on StackOverflow. I believe what you are looking for is the following. [Comparing arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713341/comparing-arrays-in-c)

```
var arraysAreEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the .NET4 feature [`Array.IStructuralEquatable.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783207.aspx) like this:

```
IStructuralEquatable equ = array1;
bool areEqual = equ.Equals(array2, EqualityComparer<string>.Default);
```

This can also be written on one line:

```
bool areEqual = (array1 as IStructuralEquatable).Equals(array2, EqualityComparer<string>.Default);
```

Using `IStructuralEquatable` has the advantage of allowing a custom comparer to be used.