# List value comparison

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out whether two string arrays are equal to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196526/how-to-find-out-whether-two-string-arrays-are-equal-to-other)

how to assert that both lists contain same items?

```
string[] arr1 = listvalue.ToArray();
string[] arr2 = listvalueMain.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
}
```

This shows an error.

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: @abatishchev, yeah I should have linked the original question :)

Comment: i am using codedUi test in VSTS

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to check that the elements are the same and in the same order.

```
bool areEqual = listvalue.SequenceEqual(listvalueMain);
```

or simply

```
Assert.IsTrue(listvalue.SequenceEqual(listvalueMain));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()` or other similar method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
foreach (string item in firstList)  
{  
    if (secondList.Contains(item))  
    {  
        MessageBox.Show("Item found" + item);  
    }
}
```

Comment: It's almost equal to 'a.Intersect(b).Any()'