# compare two identical lists of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list

Let's say I have following code:

```
    List<string> numbers = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
    List<string> numbers2 = new List<string> { "1", "2"};

    if (numbers.Equals(numbers2))
    {

    }
```

Like you can see I have two lists with identical items. Is there a way to check if these two lists are equal by using one method?

**SOLUTION:**

Use `SequenceEqual()`

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546925/comparing-two-liststring-for-equality

Comment: Is sequence item position shoudl be considered?

Comment: @Ozkan what if you had duplicates? like `numbers: { 1, 1, 2}` and `numbers2: { 1, 2 }` would you consider those equal?

Comment: @Matthew Cox, Hi, this is not considered to occur. But I found the method its `SequenceEqual()`

Comment: Before calling SequenceEqual, you have to sort the lists.

Comment: If all you want to do is "compare two identical lists of strings", then `return true` will do the job. It's also the fastest solution

Comment: Very good, that made me smile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx), but [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) the lists first.

Answer (score 2):

```
// if order does not matter
bool theSame = numbers.Except(numbers2).Count() == 0;

// if order is matter
var set = new HashSet<string>(numbers);
set.SymmetricExceptWith(numbers2);
bool theSame = set.Count == 0;
```

Comment: That would be my answer. Just depends on if duplicates matter. If they do then this would return a false positive.