# Equality between two enumerables

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, equality

I have two enumerables with the exact same reference elements, and wondering why Equals wouldn't be true.

As a side question, the code below to compare each element works, but there must be a more elegant way

```
var other = (ActivityService) obj;
if (!AllAccounts.Count().Equals(other.AllAccounts.Count())) return false;
for (int i = 0; i < AllAccounts.Count(); i++) {
    if (!AllAccounts.ElementAt(i).Equals(other.AllAccounts.ElementAt(i))) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876508/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-two-listt-lists-for-equality-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have a look at the [Enumerable.SequenceEqual method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx).

```
bool result = AllAccounts.SequenceEqual(other.AllAccounts);
```

Depending on the data type you may also need to use the [overloaded method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx) that accepts an `IEqualityComparer` to define a custom comparison method.

Answer (score 17):

.Equals is comparing the references of the *enumerables*, not the *elements* they contain.