# Fastest way of comparing two lists without using nested loops

Tags: c#, list

I have two types:

```
public class SubCategories
{
    public static List<SubCategories> subCategories = new List<SubCategories>();
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string IDfromCategories { get; set; }
    public string subCategoryID { get; set; }

    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
}

public class UserInsideCategories
{
    public string userEmail { get; set; }
    public string iDfromSubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

And two lists both containing this object multiple times.

Now I wanna go through a list with type `SubCategories` and check each object, if it contains the same value as my other list of type `UserInsideCategories`. Specifically, I wanna know if any object on the list.SubcategoryID is equal to any object on the other list.IdFromSubCateogires.

I achieved this like so:

```
List<SubCategories> branch = new List<SubCategories>();

for(int i = 0; i < subCategories.Count; i++)
{
    SubCategories e = new SubCategories();

    for(int x = 0; x < allSubs.Count; x++)
    {
        if (e.IDfromCategories == allSubs[x].iDfromSubCategories)
            e.isChecked = true;
    }

    branch.Add(e);
}
```

So I am using a nested loop. But since I have to do this multiple times, it takes far too long.

I also thought about turning all values from SubCategories into a simple string array and use the `Contains` function, to see if the current object.IDfromCategories contains the object on the array. This would mean I would NOT use a for loop. But interenally, I believe, the system is still using a loop and therefore there would be no performance benefit.

What would be the best way of checking each object if it contains a value from the other list?

Comment: It seems you're only interested in checking if `allSubs` contains an entry where `iDfromSubCategories == IDfromCategories` so I would transform all the `iDfromSubCategories` into a `HashTable` and profit from the quick lookup!

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308476/fastest-way-to-find-out-whether-two-icollectiont-collections-contain-the-same

Comment: @Knoop what you are assuming is correct. HashTable? Can you give an example?

Comment: I suppose you would profit some lookup speed if you break out of the inner loop as soon as you find first occurence.

Comment: Actually that is quite a good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some kind of lookup table. Probably either [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) or [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0). The former only allows checking if a key exists in the set, while the later allows you to also find the object the key belongs to.

To check all the `UserInsideCategories` that shares an id with a `SubCategories` you could write:

```
var dict = subCategoriesList.ToDictionary(s => s.subCategoryID, s => s);
var matches = userInsideCategoriesList.Where(l => dict.ContainsKey(l.iDfromSubCategories));
```

if you want matching pairs you could write:

```
foreach (var user in userInsideCategoriesList)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(user.iDfromSubCategories, out var subCategory))
    {
        // Handle matched pairs
    }
}
```

This assumes that the ID is unique in respective list. If you have duplicates you would need something like a multi-value dictionary. There are no multi-value dictionary built in, but I would expect there are some implementations if you search around a bit.